# Understanding code execution with ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, import, ecmascript-6

*Questions are mentioned at the bottom*

I have been using Webpack for quite some time with for my React production builds.

I got interested in ES6 modules, about code separation and execution.

So I came up with the following test code to understand the behavior of modules.

*Code is placed in the src folder. Webpack bundles the code and then `bundle.js` is run with `node ./dist/bundle.js` in the termial*

**Code:**

*./src/index.js*

```
import node1 from "./node1";   
import node2 from "./node2";

function part() {
  node1();
  node2();
}

part();
```

*./src/node1.js*

```
import test, { x } from "./test";

function node1() {
  console.log("node1", x, new Date().getTime());
  test();
  console.log("node1", x, new Date().getTime());
}

export default node1;
```

*./src/node2.js*

```
import test, { x } from "./test";

function node2() {
  console.log("node2", x, new Date().getTime());
  test();
  console.log("node2", x, new Date().getTime());
}

export default node2;
```

*./src/test.js*

```
let x = 1;
console.log(x, new Date().getTime());

function test() {
 console.log(
  "This is test for understanding dependency graph",
  x++,
  new Date().getTime()
 );
}

export default test;

export { x };
```

**Execution Result**

[image]

**Question:** I expect the exported value of `x` to remain constant. Why is 
 it not?

**Question:** Is behavior displayed during run-time because of `webpack` bundling or more inherent part of `import\export` specification of ES6 modules?

Comment: Why do you expect `x` to remain constant when the `test()` function explicitly increments it?

Comment: So I am trying to understand the behavior, modules do scoping of variables. I was expecting the exported value of `x` to remain constant, all the while since `test` is defined in the scope it should have access to the variable due to closure. There is a huge possibility that what i am asking is downright wrong, but I can't get my head around import and exports.

Comment: I am expecting my exports to be static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In ES6 module, an export value is not the real value but rather an immutable binding. Simple put `x` in `node1.j` is an immutable reference to `x` in `test.js`
2. It is by ES6 module design

You can read more here: http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html

Comment: `immutable reference` as a term explains the entire behaviour